# Stellar Community Staking Marathon

Tags: assets

I just opened a Stellar account to take advantage of the staking marathon. I can't seem to find details on it. I moved 100 xlm to this account to test it. Do the Lumens I own all have to be in this account to make them work to get free lumens from the marathon? I have quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT DO ANYTHING**

You are being scammed by an email-phishing attempt. There is no such thing as a Community Staking Marathon. Please look at email sender and you will see it is not an official email from Stellar.org.

https://twitter.com/koltenb_/status/1276276412681519106?s=21

https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/hfved3/there_is_no_staking_on_stellar/

Comment: Thank you. I moved too quickly, they got me.

Comment: Yep, it was a scam. Caught me too.

Answer (score 0):

same here  the blog and account viewer looked very much the same as the real account viewer. Good job by the scammer.

I accessed the account I created on the fake account viewer with a HW Wallet on the real account viewer but I am still unable to send back my funds. I get an error.
"message": "Request failed with status code 400",
"name": "Error",
"fileName": "https://accountviewer.stellar.org/main-d8876244d4005d764f0c.js",
"lineNumber": 40580,
"columnNumber": 16,
"stack": "createError@https://accountviewer.stellar.org/main-d8876244d4005d764f0c.js:40580:16\nsettle@https://accountviewer.stellar.org/main-d8876244d4005d764f0c.js:69562:13\nhandleLoad@https://accountviewer.stellar.org/main-d8876244d4005d764f0c.js:40403:14\n",
"config": {
"url": "https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions",
"method": "post",
"data": "tx=AAAAABK4vfWX7AnBty8Xj6239U2ctRZQLaPBA1wOgEoYm1K5AAAAZAHOx70AAAADAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF78TbwAAAABAAAAClpRTlFDSExYS1EAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAALhnFw7PTp3BYp7Jmx1o13KD00ePlFArUJS7MzTBYWsAAAAAAAAAAJRXT6OAAAAAAAAAABGJtSuQAAAEDhsEuR8RNUADY9PEmssBrCWJ4VeQq4i3xUaXSPG9z2gtd3RbjaF3xwVTALLh5XtMyjH8dhStgEQZpRo7DK86ID",
"headers": {
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"X-Client-Name": "js-stellar-sdk",
"X-Client-Version": "5.0.0"
},
"transformRequest": [
null
],
"transformResponse": [
null
],
"timeout": 60000,
"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength": -1
}
}

Any clues as to why  the operation fails

Thank you